# What are some possible causes of this Kotlin Retrofit2 error?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2, jetbrains-ide

What are some possible causes of this Kotlin Retrofit2 error?  My JSON was converting correctly when I had coded this using enqueue.  I updated it to use Deferred and Response and I'm now getting this error.

```
Unable to create converter for kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred<retrofit2.Response<com.smate.data.apiResponse.GenericApiResponse>>
```

It refers to this section of my code:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("validIdentification")
suspend fun isValidIdentificationAsync(@Body identification: Identification): Deferred<Response<GenericApiResponse>>
```

Here's the GenericApiResponse class:

```
package com.smate.data.apiResponse

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class GenericApiResponse(
    var isValid:String
) {
    val isValidBoolean: Boolean
        get() = isValid.toBoolean()
}
```

This is the calling function:

```
override suspend fun isValidIdentification(identification: Identification): ValidationResult {
    try {
        val response = sMateApiService.isValidIdentificationAsync(identification).await()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val genericResponse: GenericApiResponse? = response.body()
            if (genericResponse != null) {
                return ValidationResult.Success(genericResponse.isValidBoolean)
            }
        } else {
            return ValidationResult.Error("API call failed")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return ValidationResult.Error("An error occurred: ${e.message}")
    }

    return ValidationResult.Error("Unexpected error")
}
```

I'm implementing these in my gradle file:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.0"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0"
```

Comment: Given your current code, you do not need `Deferred`, as all you do is `await()` on it. You could eliminate the `Deferred`, which might help. If you are very certain that you want `Deferred`, try removing the `suspend` keyword from the `isValidIdentificationAsync()` function declaration.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare.  I removed the Deferred and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin coroutines, `Deferred` is a type of `Job` representing an ongoing coroutine. I *think* Retrofit has support for `Deferred`, though I do not recall using it.

Retrofit definitely has support for `suspend fun`, which also has the work be done via a coroutine.

Your code is attempting to use both: the function is declared as `suspend fun` *and* it is returning a `Deferred`. That seems unnecessary, as you should only need one to represent that the work should be executed in a coroutine.

As discussed in question comments, you removed the `Deferred` and the problem went away. Because of the `suspend fun`, your network I/O still will be performed in a coroutine, using Retrofit's default dispatcher.